# bluetooth battery level indicator/display

Tags: bluetooth, 19.10

is there any way to display or check bluetooth battery level for a2dp non BLE devices such as my JBL earphones.

model JBL E25BT.

when connected to android is shows me the accurate battery levels.

how to get this on ubuntu 19.10 as well.
or is this planned in future updates?

Comment: With upower --enumerate you could list all batteries in your computer. With path and -i switch you can see status of the battery.

Comment: upower --enumerate just lists the line power and laptop battery in my case.
no bluetooth devices listed even when connected.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a GUI application to get the battery level of a bluetooth headset and I tested it with my JBL tune 500bt You can check it on: https://github.com/Coutj/Bluetooth_project.git